# Is it possible to get caret position in Word to update faster?

Tags: c#, ms-word, keyboard-hook

I'm using a low level keyboard hook and `GUITHREADINFO` to get caret position in Windows applications on every keyup.

Works well for almost all applications - except Word. For some reason Word only updates the position of the caret after some arbitrary delay (meaning the position will always be off one or more characters).

I can get correct position if I wait a couple hundred milliseconds (`Thread.Sleep(400)` for example) before fetching the position - but this usable solution for the application I'm working on.

**Any way I can get the correct caret position faster? Either by forcing Word to render the caret, using a Word specific function, subscribing to a Word event or something entirely different?**

Keyboard hook class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace CS_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class that manages a global low level keyboard hook
    /// </summary>
    public class GlobalKeyboardHook
    {
        #region Constant, Structure and Delegate Definitions
        /// <summary>
        /// defines the callback type for the hook
        /// </summary>
        public delegate int KeyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);

        private static KeyboardHookProc _callbackDelegate;

        public struct KeyboardHookStruct // C++ KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT 
        {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        const int WH_KEYBOARD = 2;
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
        const int LLKHF_INJECTED = 0x10;
        #endregion

        #region Instance Variables
        /// <summary>
        /// The collections of keys to watch for
        /// </summary>
        public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle to the hook, need this to unhook and call the next hook
        /// </summary>
        IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

        private bool _ignoreInjected = false;
        private bool _shiftHeld = false;
        private bool _ctrlHeld = false;
        private bool _altHeld = false;

        #endregion

        #region Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is pressed
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is released
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> class and installs the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        public GlobalKeyboardHook(bool ignoreInjected)
        {
            _ignoreInjected = ignoreInjected;
            Hook();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Releases unmanaged resources and performs other cleanup operations before the
        /// <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> is reclaimed by garbage collection and uninstalls the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            Unhook();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Installs the global hook
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        private void Hook()
        {
            _callbackDelegate = new KeyboardHookProc(HookProc);
            //IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            //hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, callbackDelegate, hInstance, 0);
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _callbackDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            if (hhook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uninstalls the global hook
        /// </summary>
        public bool Unhook()
        {
            try
            {
                bool ok = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
                if (!ok) throw new Win32Exception();
                _callbackDelegate = null;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The callback for the keyboard hook
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="code">The hook code, if it isn't >= 0, the function shouldn't do anyting</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The event type</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The keyhook event information</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// 
        public int HookProc(int code, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0)
            {
                // Continue only if injected keys are allowed or key is not injected
                if (!_ignoreInjected || (lParam.flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == 0)
                {
                    // Determine modifiers
                    if (lParam.vkCode == 160 || lParam.vkCode == 161) // LShiftKey / RShiftKey
                    {
                        _shiftHeld = (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN);
                    }
                    else if (lParam.vkCode == 162 || lParam.vkCode == 163) // LControlKey / RControlKey
                    {
                        _ctrlHeld = (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN);
                    }
                    else if (lParam.vkCode == 164 || lParam.vkCode == 165) // LMenu / RMenu aka LAlt / RAlt
                    {
                        // We can also determine if Alt is held by checking if bit 5 (0-indexed) of lParam.flags is set
                        _altHeld = (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN);
                    }

                    Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                    if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                    {
                        Keys keyModified = key;
                        if (_shiftHeld) keyModified |= Keys.Shift;
                        if (_ctrlHeld) keyModified |= Keys.Control;
                        if (_altHeld) keyModified |= Keys.Alt;
                        KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(keyModified);

                        // Call keydown event handlers
                        if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                        {
                            KeyDown(this, kea);
                        }

                        // Call keyup event handlers
                        else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                        {
                            KeyUp(this, kea);
                        }

                        // Check if any of the handlers have handled the event
                        if (kea.Handled)
                        {
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                // This can crash if Windows has decided to unhook the proc during this function
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GlobalKeyboardHook exception: " + ex.Message);
                return 0;
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region DLL imports
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the windows hook, do the desired event, one of hInstance or threadId must be non-null
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The id of the event you want to hook</param>
        /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The handle you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <param name="threadId">The thread you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <returns>a handle to the desired hook</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Unhooks the windows hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The hook handle that was returned from SetWindowsHookEx</param>
        /// <returns>True if successful, false otherwise</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the next hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The hook id</param>
        /// <param name="nCode">The hook code</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The wparam.</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The lparam.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the library.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpFileName">Name of the library</param>
        /// <returns>A handle to the library</returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        #endregion
    }

    public class KeyboardHookLogEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message;
        public KeyboardHookLogEventArgs(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

The caret helper class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CS_test
{
    public class CaretInfo
    {
        public double Width { get; private set; }
        public double Height { get; private set; }
        public double Left { get; private set; }
        public double Top { get; private set; }

        public CaretInfo(double width, double height, double left, double top)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Left = left;
            Top = top;
        }
    }

    public class CaretHelper
    {

        public static CaretInfo GetCaretPosition()
        {
            // Get GUI info containing caret poisition
            var guiInfo = new GUITHREADINFO();
            guiInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(guiInfo);
            GetGUIThreadInfo(0, out guiInfo);

            // Convert caret position to position relative to top left corner of current editor window - it seems like this is not neccessary
            /*var caretInfo = new System.Windows.Point();
            caretInfo.X = guiInfo.rcCaret.left;
            caretInfo.Y = guiInfo.rcCaret.top;
            ClientToScreen(guiInfo.hwndCaret, out caretInfo);*/

            // Get width/height
            double width = guiInfo.rcCaret.right - guiInfo.rcCaret.left;
            double height = guiInfo.rcCaret.bottom - guiInfo.rcCaret.top;

            // Get left/top relative to screen
            RECT rect;
            GetWindowRect(guiInfo.hwndFocus, out rect);

            double left = guiInfo.rcCaret.left + rect.left + 2; // Seems to always be 2 pixels off
            double top = guiInfo.rcCaret.top + rect.top + 2; // Seems to always be 2 pixels off

            return new CaretInfo(width, height, left, top);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetGUIThreadInfo")]
        public static extern bool GetGUIThreadInfo(uint tId, out GUITHREADINFO threadInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, out Point position);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr handle, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct GUITHREADINFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public uint flags;
            public IntPtr hwndActive;
            public IntPtr hwndFocus;
            public IntPtr hwndCapture;
            public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
            public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
            public IntPtr hwndCaret;
            public RECT rcCaret;
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

WPF MainWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CS_test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GlobalKeyboardHook hook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(true);
            foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys))) // Add keys that KeyboardHook should listen for
            {
                if (key != Keys.Control && key != Keys.ControlKey)
                {
                    hook.HookedKeys.Add(key);
                }
            }
            hook.KeyUp += hook_KeyUp;
        }

        void hook_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            CaretInfo info = CaretHelper.GetCaretPosition();
            Console.WriteLine(info.Left + ", " + info.Top);
        }
    }
}
```

Try typing 3 letters in quick succession - should yield a log with the same coordinates for all three keyups.

Comment: It is a fair miracle that it works at all, Microsoft has not used GDI in Office programs for a very long time.  Must be quite a nightmare keeping their code compatible with programs hat try to hack it like this.  Lossage is pretty inevitable, especially the slick animation effects in 2013 are bound to cause this kind of problem.  Don't do it.

Comment: Exactly why is this hacky? Also, could you point towards any alternatives?